# Nonlinear Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I have the code (taken from Mathematica)::

```
  Manipulate[If[ct, DensityPlot, Plot3D][Evaluate[Abs@u[If[ct, x0 - t, t], x] /.Quiet[NDSolve[[{I D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
      Abs[u[t, x]]^2 u[t, x] == 1/2 (x^2) u[t, x], 
    u[0, x] == E^-(x)^2, u[t, -x0] == u[t, x0]}], 
  u, {t, 0, x0}, {x, -x0, x0}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral", 
      "MinStepSize" -> 0.2}}]]],{x, -x0, x0},{t, 0, 10},Mesh -> mesh, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> Full,ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 30,MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, 2], ImageSize -> {475, 325}, ImagePadding -> 15], {{a, 1., "initial peak separation"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{x0, 10., "solutions range"}, 1, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{mesh, Automatic, "show mesh"}, {False, Automatic}, ControlType -> Checkbox}, {{ct, True, "Plot type"}, {True -> "2D",  False -> "3D"}, ControlType -> SetterBar},ControllerLinking -> True,ControlPlacement -> Top, SynchronousInitialization -> False]
```

It works well for some potentials, like the harmonic oscillator, but for the  square well potential I don't obtain a solution.

```
Manipulate[If[ct, DensityPlot, Plot3D][Evaluate[Abs@y[If[ct, x0 - t, t], x] /. 
Quiet[NDSolve[
  Evaluate[{I D[y[t, x], t] + D[y[t, x], x, x] + 
      Abs[y[t, x]]^2 y[t, x] == v[x, h]*y[x, t], 
    y[0, t] == E^-(x)^2, y[-x0, t] == y[x0, t]}], 
  y, {t, 0, x0}, {x, -x0, x0}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral", 
      "MinStepSize" -> 0.2}}]]], {x, -x0, x0}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> mesh, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> Full, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, 2], ImageSize -> {475, 325}, ImagePadding -> 15], {{x0, 10., "solutions range"}, 1, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{mesh, Automatic, "show mesh"}, {False, Automatic}, ControlType -> Checkbox}, {{ct, True, "Plot type"}, {True -> "2D", False -> "3D"}, ControlType -> SetterBar}, Delimiter, {{h, 10, "well depth "}, 2, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControllerLinking -> True, ControlPlacement -> Top, SynchronousInitialization -> False, Initialization :> (v[x_, h_] := Piecewise[{{h, x < -0.5}, {h, x > 0.5}}, 0];)]
```

Can someone tell me why it does not work for this potential?  and, if possible, tell me how to solve it

Comment: One thing is that `t, x` need to be ordered consistently, you can not then have `x, t`

Comment: For the square well you need to use boundary conditions where the wavefunction is set to zero at the well edges $\pm x_0$: something like `y[-x0,t] == y[x0,t] == 0`.